# Actual column name after flattening Nested JSON using PySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, nested, databricks

I have flatten the nested JSON file now I am facing an ambiguity issue to get the actual column name using PySpark.

Dataframe with the following schema:

Before flattening:

```
root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
```

After Flattening:

```
root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- foo_a: float (nullable = true)
 |-- foo_b: float (nullable = true)
 |-- foo_c: integer (nullable = true)
```

Is it possible to get only the actual name of the column in Data Frame as shown below:

```
root
 |-- x: string (nullable = true)
 |-- y: string (nullable = true)
 |-- a: float (nullable = true)
 |-- b: float (nullable = true)
 |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just do following instead of flattening:

```
select("*", "foo.*").drop("foo")
```

or

```
select("x", "y", "foo.*")
```

The `foo.*` syntax pulls all fields from the struct and put them into the "top-level"